# Priority wise Selection from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Have a look into the follwing data from a table.

```
id | type_id | condition_id |
-----------------------------
21    MMM       YES
21    CCC       YES
22    CCC       YES
22    MMM       YES
23    MMM       YES
23    -         YES
23    CCC       YES
24    CCC       YES
25    -         YES
26    CCC       YES
26    -         YES
```

I want a select query output for the above data as :

```
id | type_id | condition_id |
-----------------------------
21    MMM       YES
22    MMM       YES
23    MMM       YES
24    CCC       YES  
25    -         YES
26    -         YES
```

It follows a priority kind of selection from a table that if type_id='MMM' is available then it should be selected otherwise type_id='-' would be selected and then type_id='CCC' will be selected. But each record should be selected for only one id value.
Any help would be very useful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, I think the easiest method is to order by your criteria and then take the first row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @id := -1, @rn := 0) vars
      order by id, field(type_id, 'MMM', '-', 'CCC')
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```